# How to display module variables in a waveform window in Vivado

Tags: verilog, vivado

I wrote a module in Verilog (Vivado) and a tesbench for it. Simulation gives me a waveform window for all variables of the testbench. Is it also possible to display the variables within the module in a waveform window? (Im using Vivado 2015.4)

thx

Comment: What kind of waveform is generated? If VCD then check out `$dumpvars` in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section 21.7 _Value change dump (VCD) files_

Answer (score 2):

If you click the UUT or any module at any level in the hierarchy, the list of "local variables" to that module appears and may be dragged to the waveform views.

When you open the sim, the default selected module is just top, that is why you only see the testbench variables.

It is so easy that I sometimes don't even bother assigning the output ports of the UUT in the test fixture, just grab them from the hierarchy.

[image]